# group by not filter result in capital letter

Tags: mysql, group-by

When i used group by in mySQL database on varchar columns.

the result is not filter properly that query marge all the values either in small letter or capital letter.

E.g. "test" and "TEST" got merge in single row..

Answer (score 1):

You can always convert the column to binary in the GROUP BY.

```
SELECT columnName
FROM tableName
GROUP BY CAST(columnName as BINARY)
```